# How to discover that appsettings changed in C#?

Tags: c#, service

Is there a way to (event will be the best option), which will notice my code that app settings changed?

Exactly I am trying to implement a windows service in which administrator should change behavior "online" without restarting service.

I was thinking about `FileSystemWatcher`, but in this option I will have to hardcode path and name to config file, so maybe there is other way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

Below answers suggests to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` but this option will not work if I have external config file defined like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="appsettings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm. I wonder whether getting users to change a file that is conceptually read-only (if you're doing things right then it's going to be in `Program Files` which requires elevated permission for changes) is really the best way to allow users to effect change on your service. I'd consider a helper app that runs at user logon that can communicate change to your service (likely by using WCF) and to use the settings.settings framework for these settings.

Comment: What is this service supposed to do?

Comment: @spender You option will much more complicated for administrators and for testing. Simple change in file is always much more easy to manage.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg does it matter, what it does? Do you see different approach for different solutions?

Comment: That's possibly true. Given that the app.config contains many other settings that are critical to successful application launch, might it not be better to place these settings in their own config file that sits in the service user's appdata folder? That way critical and non-critical settings are isolated from one another.

Comment: This is a critical section and critical flag. Anyway it is a business requirement and I do not have a choice

Comment: @garath I was thinking about a scheduling component named Quartz.Net which is used to execute jobs a certain times. A bonus feature it has is config file monitoring. And you can have custom settings along with the scheduling config. If your service does perform scheduled tasks or if it can run in such a context, Quartz.Net would solve your entire problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` with the path from this statement:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

No need for hard coded paths.

Comment: it won't work if I have external appsettings defined like: `<appSettings configSource="appsettings.config"/>`

Comment: Of course it would. Use the above mentioned path, use whatever method you like and look for the configSource attribute and monitor that as well. Make it super generic, post it on GitHub, create a nuget package and become super famous. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe by using timer in a background thread and checking each 5 seconds the config  file checksum If changed than fire config changed event.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` is much better than `Timer` and still I will have same problems like harcoding path and name. Also I will have to reread config file.

Comment: no the path is no problem you can get it from :AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile but I gree that the FileSystemWatcher is a better soultion because you less than using of CPU and memory.